# Render image from byte stream stored in mako template in mako template

Tags: mysql, django, image, python-2.7

I am working in Django framework. I have stored image in mysql table. When I access my mysql table from views.py file this image appears as byte stream text whose tyep is string, I want to know how can I pass this byte stream to my img tag in html so that it will appear on my screen.

P.S. I do not want to store this image and then pass its source.

Comment: I got the solution on this link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31358578/display-image-stored-as-binary-blob-in-template