# How to display images in Django?

Tags: python, html, django

I have an inventory system. When I click a medicine, it shows this specific medicine's information. This page is medicine_details.html. When I open, I get all the correct information, but I cannot see the image. When I open the page in inspect there is an error:

```
<img src=(unknown) alt="img">
```

How can I fix it?

**views.py**

```
def medicine_detail(request, id):
    medicine = get_object_or_404(Medicine, id=id)
    context = {
        'medicine': medicine,
    }
    return render(request, 'medicine_details.html', context)
```

**models.py**

```
class Medicine(models.Model):

    medicine_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    medicine_info = RichTextField(verbose_name="notes")
    medicine_code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    medicine_qr = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    medicine_price = models.IntegerField()
    medicine_stock = models.IntegerField()
    medicine_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True, editable=False)

    def get_image(self):
        if self.medicine_image and hasattr(self.medicine_image, 'url'):
            return self.medicine_image.url
        else:
            return

    def __str__(self):
        return self.medicine_name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['medicine_name']

    def get_create_url(self):
        return reverse('medicines:medicine_create', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def get_unique_slug(self):
        slug = slugify(self.slug.replace('ı', 'i'))
        unique_slug = slug
        counter = 1
        while Medicine.objects.filter(slug=unique_slug).exists():
            unique_slug = '{}-{}'.format(slug, counter)
            counter += 1
        return unique_slug

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('medicines:medicine_create', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = self.get_unique_slug()
        return super(Medicine, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**medicine_details.html**

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading text-center"><h3>{{medicine.medicine_name}} </h3></div>
                    <div class="panel-body">


                        <h4><p class="text-success">Medicine Name:  <small>{{medicine.medicine_name}}</small></h4>
                        <h4><p class="text-success">Details:  <small>{{medicine.medicine_info}}</small></h4>
                        <h4><p class="text-success">Barcode:  <small>{{medicine.medicine_code}}</small></h4>
                        <h4><p class="text-success">QR:  <small>{{medicine.medicine_qr}}</small></h4>
                        <h4><p class="text-success">Price:  <small>{{medicine.medicine_price}} TL</small></h4>
                        <h4><p class="text-success"> <small></small></h4>
                        <img src="{{ medicine.medicine_image.url }}" alt="img">
```

**settings.py**

...

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**urls.py**
...

```
url(r'^medicines/(?P<id>\d+)/$', medicine_detail, name="detail"),


    ]
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I use MySQL for database management.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
{% if medicine.medicine_image %}
<img src="{{STATIC_URL}} {{ medicine.medicine_image.url }}" alt="img">
{% endif %}
```

In your settings file you should have:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
```

If this doesn't work, please post what error you get.

Comment: It does not work but it show the  ALT text and left of it there is a broken picture icon

Comment: Do you have `{% load static % }` on the top of your page?

Comment: Yes. For example when I add image from admin panel, I quit from that page and open again the image is dissapear like I never added it.

Comment: I wrote wrong something in urls.py I fixed it and edited my question now when I add image from admin panel I get an error: 
expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple

Comment: Make sure there is no comma after your BASE_DIR. You must have an extra comma somewhere, because it is picking something up as a tuple that shouldn't be one.

Comment: Yes I fixed it but still don't work. :( I guess I should write all over again.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `{{ medicine.medicine_image.url }}` with

`/media/{{ medicine.medicine_image.url }}`

Answer (score 0):

In your settings, set:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

ensure that `django.template.context_processors.media` in the `context_processors` option of `TEMPLATES`

```
# settings
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
         ...
        "OPTIONS": {
            ...
            "context_processors": [
                ...
                "django.template.context_processors.media",
            ],
        },
    }
]
```

then in your template, you can use:

```
<img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{medicine.medicine_image}}" alt="img">
```

*note: no backslash after `{{MEDIA_URL}}`*

Comment: @eda have you changed the image name?, b'img_medicine/apranax_3ISERzD.jpg'  is `bytes` not `str`

Comment: I changed medicine name as 0.jpg and I get error: [28/Jun/2020 22:11:17] "GET /medicines/6/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2950
Not Found: /media/b'img_medicine/0_Ga1GI77.jpg'

Comment: it seems that you somehow breaks the normal storage behavior, the file path should never be a `bytes` object, if it is `bytes` object, you could not save the image in first place.

Comment: I use mysql database and I made medicine_image is blob. Is it okey or not?

Comment: it's much easier and advisable to use file system for storage though

Comment: @eda if its `blob`, you can have a look of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31358578/display-image-stored-as-binary-blob-in-template. BTW, you need to read the content of the file and save as blob, but not the path(name) as binary