# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'product_img' Python, Flask, SQLite

Tags: python, html, sqlite, flask

I'm trying to display text and image on template from SQLite database.
Database model:

```
class NewProduct(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    product_name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    product_description = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    product_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    product_img = db.Column(db.BLOB())

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<NewProduct %r>' % self.id
```

Function to display information from db in .html:

```
@app.route('/products')
def products():
    products = NewProduct.query.order_by(NewProduct.product_date.desc()).all()
    product_img = b64encode(products.product_img).decode('utf-8')
    return render_template('products.html', products=products, image=product_img)
```

HTML:

```
<body>
{% if products|length > 0 %}

    {% for el in products %}
        <p>Name: {{ el.product_name }}</p>
        <p>Description: {{ el.product_description }}</p>
        <p>Image: </p> <img src="data:;base64,{{ image }}">
        <p>Date: {{ el.product_date }}</p>
    {% endfor %}

{% else %}
    <p>There are have no products</p>
{% endif %}
```

So, I'm get an error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'product_img'` in line `product_img = b64encode(products.product_img).decode('utf-8')`

I did it for this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31358578/display-image-stored-as-binary-blob-in-template). But I anyway get this error. What I'm doing whong and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access `product_img` for a list of `products`, not on a single object. You need to iterate through the objects and update the value for each of them:

```
@app.route('/products')
def products():
    products = NewProduct.query.order_by(NewProduct.product_date.desc()).all()
    for product in products:
        product.product_img = b64encode(product.product_img).decode('utf-8')
    return render_template('products.html', products=products)
```

Then update your template to get the value from the `product` object:

```
<body>
{% if products|length > 0 %}

    {% for el in products %}
        <p>Name: {{ el.product_name }}</p>
        <p>Description: {{ el.product_description }}</p>
        <p>Image: </p> <img src="data:;base64,{{ el.product_img }}">
        <p>Date: {{ el.product_date }}</p>
    {% endfor %}

{% else %}
    <p>There are have no products</p>
{% endif %}
```

I would also suggest to remove the prefix `product_` from your variables, as it seems redundant and makes your code less readable.

Answer (score 2):

`products` is a list so the line  `products.product_img` raise the error you are facing. If you need to convert the image into something else you need to loop over the `products` and modify the image of each product.