# Flask TypeError TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'NoneType'

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I want to add images into sqlalchemy in flask and I tried to do it from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64536349/attributeerror-list-object-has-no-attribute-product-img-python-flask-sqli).

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,request,Response
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from base64 import b64encode
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///users1.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
class Images(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text)
    img =  db.Column(db.Text)

db.create_all()
mylist = []
@app.route('/',methods=['POST','GET'])
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        img1 = request.files['ab']
        imager = img1.save(secure_filename(img1.filename))
        imager = Images(name='abc',img=img1.read())
        db.session.add(imager)
        db.session.commit()
    return render_template('other.html')

@app.route('/allimages',methods=['POST','GET'])
def home1():
    mylist1 = Images.query.filter_by(name='abc').all()
    for i in mylist1:
        image = b64encode(i.img)
    return render_template('new.html',posts=image)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

But when I go to `allimages` I get `TypeError TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'NoneType'`. What should I do? I get the error in the browser and also in the console.

Thanks.

Comment: In the post you reference, the image column is a binary type, `BLOB`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you forgot to use the `decode` method of `b64encode`.

But also you're overwriting image, each time in the for loop.  Going by the linked question you should be adding a new attribute to each `image` in `images`, in this case `uri_src`:

```
    images = Images.query.filter_by(name='abc').all()
    for image in images:
        image.uri_src = b64encode(image.img).decode('utf-8')

    # Now pass images (plural) to the template 
    return render_template('new.html',posts=images)
```

Then handle this in the template like:

```
{% for image in posts %}
    <p>Name: {{ image.name }}</p>
    <p>Image: </p> <img src="data:;base64,{{ image.uri_src }}">
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I still get the same error. What should I do?

Comment: @KenKaneki the traceback should show **which line** caused the Exception.  Can you post this?

Comment: I changed the ``img`` column with LargeBinary and now I don't get any error. But the image does not seem and there is a picture of a file.

Comment: I don't get any exception now. But do you have any solution?

Comment: Please reply. Do you have any solution?